# A difficult limit -> problem in getting out of the form $\infty \times 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence which converges to $l$. Moreover we have : $\mid x_n -l\mid \leq C \mid x_{n-1}-l\mid, C \in ]0,1[$ and : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-l}{x_n-l} = k \in ]0,1[$. Find :
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x_n-l} \left(\frac{x_{n+1}-l}{x_n-l} - k\right)$$

I am quite sure the answer is $0$, yet I am not able to prove it... Here we are dealing with a limit of the form $+\infty \times 0$ and I can't get out of this form.

Somehow I need to show that $(x_{n+1}-l)/(x_n-l)$ converges quicker than $1/x_n^2$.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality we can consider $\ell=0$, else just set $u_n=x_n-l$ satisfying the same conditions.

Note that the limit condition implies the $C$ inequality condition, since a convergent sequence is bounded (take $C=k+\varepsilon<1$ since $k\in]0,1[$ open interval, for instance $\varepsilon=\frac{1-k}2$ works).

But the condition $x_{n+1}\sim k\,x_n$ seems not enough to conclude.

Let's take for instance $x_n=k^n + (\frac k2)^n$

Since $0<\frac k2<k<1$ then $(\frac k2)^n=o(k^n)$ and we have $x_n\sim k^n$ verifying the hypothesis.

Yet $\quad\dfrac 1{x_n}\left(\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-k\right)=\cdots=-\dfrac 12\dfrac{2^nk}{k^n(2^n+1)^2}\sim\dfrac{-2^nk}{2k^n2^n2^n}\sim-\dfrac k2\dfrac{1}{(2k)^n}$

Thus depending whether $k<\dfrac 12$ we can have a limit $0,-\frac 14,-\infty$